# Upgrade pip in virtual environment

Tags: python, pip, python-venv

I tried to upgrade pip in virtual environment.
I have error as follows.

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/itc/intel/training_extensions/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/itc/intel/training_extensions/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 290, in run
    with self._build_session(options) as session:
  File "/home/itc/intel/training_extensions/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 69, in _build_session
    if options.cache_dir else None
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/posixpath.py", line 80, in join
    a = os.fspath(a)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not int
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with `options.cache_dir`. It's just a speed optimization, so not essential.

Upgrade pip with `python -m pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir pip` to bypass the broken code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it with this command:

```
pip install --no-cache -U pip
```

Answer (score 0):

First, try pip upgrade with the below commands.

Linux or  macOS

```
$ python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

For Windows:

```
py -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

or try it:

*pip provides an on-by-default caching, designed to reduce the amount of time spent on duplicate downloads and builds.*

```
pip install --no-cache -U pip
```

**If it still shows any error then remove the virtual environment and install it again. Many times such problems arise due to system complexity.**

Answer (score -1):

sometimes python does not recognise your statement therefore it gives these errors.

Try this:-
Python -m pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: This doesn't work - the error happens (as the question says) when you use this command to upgrade pip. It's one of the worst software engineering errors - breaking your upgrade path, so you can't even fix it with an upgrade.